# How to do a router change on Angular2 from an observable error in a provider?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-routing

We issue refresh tokens in our authentication process. This is handled by `token.service.ts` which is a provider.  When we detect a 401, we go and trigger this refresh token process. However, we've noticed that in the case where there is an error with this refresh token method, we are having problems kicking the user out of the app. We'd ideally like to push them back to the outside, so they can log in again. But this doesn't seem to be working. There is no error, it just doesn't make the route change. The line of code in the error is `this.router.navigate(["/login"]);`. The problem is this error could happen anywhere in the app so we have to handle it in a central place. Is it that its not possible to do router changes from a provider?

```
token.service.ts

refreshToken(): Observable<any> {

        let params = "grant_type=refresh_token" +
            "&refresh_token=" + Config.refreshToken;

        return this.http.post(this.authApiBaseUrl + '/token', params)
            .map(this.mapToken)
            .catch(this.handleRefreshTokenError);

    }

private handleRefreshTokenError(error: any) {

    console.log('error refreshing token, ejecting user');
    Config.invalidateToken();
    this.router.navigate(["/login"]);

    return Observable.throw("REFRESH_TOKEN_FAILED");

}

export const TOKEN_PROVIDER: any = [

    {
        provide: TokenService, useFactory: (http: Http, router: Router) => {
            return new TokenService(http,router);
        }, deps: [Http, Router]

    }
```

Comment: Routing in a service definitely works. It's how I'm handling authentication in my app.  What error are you getting?  or is it just not redirecting?

Comment: Hey Dave, it's just not redirecting, there's no error

Comment: Do you inject the router in your service?

Comment: Not a solution to your problem but I'm pretty sure just using `providers: [TokenService]` will do the same as `providers: [TOKEN_PROVIDER]`. I don't see anything in your code that would require a factory.

Comment: Where do you provide the `TOKEN_PROVIDER`?